# Significance test for trend in time series with multiple sets of observations

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, trend, games

Tomorrow there will be a race in which six runners participate in the 100 m dash. I will be able to capture the speed of each runner at each meter, so for each runner there will be a time series with 100 measurements. My hypothesis is that the runners will be at their fastest at around meter 65 or so, and then they will start to tire out. Therefore the curves in general will look like a upside down U. The null hypothesis is that there's no relationship between distance into the 100m dash and speed. My question is, is there a statistical test to support the conclusion that there is a relationship between distance into the race and speed? If so, is there a post hoc test to show that one particular meter is actually the fastest?

To confirm, I want to carry it out this test over all six runners, not for each runner individually.

Would a one-way ANOVA with post hoc Turkey test for multiple comparisons be appropriate?

Comment: Clearly the null hypothesis of a constant speed must be false on physical grounds: the speed at the start is zero and so (excluding infinite acceleration) will be lower shortly after the start than later in the race.   That does not detract from your question of identifying the point of top expected speed based on your sample of the six runners

Comment: You might want to look at the chart 2/3 of the way down a [Quanta article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/infinite-powers-usain-bolt-and-the-art-of-calculus-20190403/) of Usain Bolt’s instantaneous speeds in the 2009 World Championships.  One issue is that speed varies during a stride and a stride is about 2 meters long.

Comment: Let's assume for our purposes that the strides are considerably shorter than a meter and so don't affect our measurements. Let's assume that they have a lead in so they're already going by the starting line.